# Double the rent doubles the house value also in monopoly deal

Tags: monopoly-deal

If there is one full set of blue card the rent value is 8m, with a house on it it is 11m.
If a player plays double the rent cards, what amount should be payed? 8+8+3m or 11+11m?

Answer (score 3):

22m - the rent is the total you need to pay, house and property, not just the base value of the property with the houses added in afterwards.